# perl mechanize empty cookies

Tags: perl, cookies, mechanize

i have the following perl code :

```
my %conf = ( file => ".cookies", autosave => 1, destroy_at_the_end => 0 );
my $mech_instance = WWW::Mechanize->new(        
        cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new(
            file           => $conf{file},
            autosave       => $conf{autosave},
            ignore_discard => $conf{destroy_at_the_end},        
        ));

$mech_instance->agent_alias('Linux Mozilla');
my $url = "http://challenge01.root-me.org/programmation/ch8/";

$mech_instance->get($url);
$mech_instance->cookie_jar->save("cookies");
```

However both "cookies" and ".cookies" files are empty.
I'm trying to solve a captcha related exercise on rootme, but the server won't accept my solutions, probably because the cookies aren't stored properly.

All documentation seems to indicate that mechanize should be able to work with cookies easily. (I should not even have to manually set the cookie_jar, according to the docs).

Does anyone know what is going on ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The server refuses connections for me. Nonetheless, the `.cookies` file is created. If I change the server to `www.google.com`, I get the cookie as expected from that server... So your code seems to work as intended.

Comment: *"Root-Me: A fast, accessible and realistic platform to test your hacking skills"* I really don't think I want to help you with this.

Comment: @Borodin Learning how to break things is the best way to learn how to secure things. You need to know how attack works to effectively protect against them. There is absolutely nothing wrong with whitehat/recreational hacking, so long as you aren't breaking into other people's production systems.

Comment: @meagar: Of course. But I hoped that there was also nothing wrong with raising a flag asking whether a post like this was acceptable on *Stack Overflow*. It seems that we must be all-knowing, as simple questions on *Meta* are also quickly destroyed.

Comment: @TomB: I suggest that you start using the `LWP` suite. `WWW::Mechanize` subclasses `LWP::UserAgent` and is meant as a very simple emulation of browser behaviour; it doesn't even support JavaScript. If you're looking at low-level hacking techniques then `Mechanize` doesn't cut it.

Comment: I tried loading that url and got an unable to connect message, either the site is down, or login first?.  Anyway, you would be good to check your `status` after the `get` to see that you actually fetched the page.  If there is no content...there is no cookie.